# Multiple single-line for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am using this data: [NVD CVE data](https://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-2018.json.zip)

My code is:

```
import json
with open('nvdcve-1.0-2018.json') as f:
    CVE = json.loads(f.read())

for x in CVE["CVE_Items"]:
    if x["cve"]["affects"]["vendor"]["vendor_data"]: # Check data exists
        description = x["cve"]["description"]["description_data"][0]["value"]
        cve = x["cve"]["CVE_data_meta"]["ID"]
        vendor = x["cve"]["affects"]["vendor"]["vendor_data"][0]["vendor_name"]
        product = x["cve"]["affects"]["vendor"]["vendor_data"][0]["product"]["product_data"][0]["product_name"]
        version = x["cve"]["affects"]["vendor"]["vendor_data"][0]["product"]["product_data"][0]["version"]["version_data"]
        version = [x["version_value"] for x in version]
        references = [x["url"] for x in x["cve"]["references"]["reference_data"]]
        print references
```

Expected output

```
[u'https://github.com/D0neMkj/POC_BSOD/tree/master/Advanced%20SystemCare%20Utimate/Monitor_win7_x64.sys-0x9c4060d0']

[u'https://github.com/D0neMkj/POC_BSOD/tree/master/Advanced%20SystemCare%20Utimate/Monitor_win7_x64.sys-0x9c402004']

[u'https://github.com/D0neMkj/POC_BSOD/tree/master/Advanced%20SystemCare%20Utimate/Monitor_win7_x86.sys-0x9c4060c4']

...
...
```

The code returns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
KeyError: 'cve'
```

The key `'cve'` does exist:

```
>>> for x in CVE["CVE_Items"]:
...     x["cve"].keys()
...
[u'description', u'data_type', u'affects', u'data_format', u'problemtype', u'data_version', u'references', u'CVE_data_meta']
[u'description', u'data_type', u'affects', u'data_format', u'problemtype', u'data_version', u'references', u'CVE_data_meta']
[u'description', u'data_type', u'affects', u'data_format', u'problemtype', u'data_version', u'references', u'CVE_data_meta']
...
...
```

If I remove the two `version =` lines (11-12), the code works as expected.

I'm thinking the issue is more likely to be me, rather than Python, but I'd like to understand why this error is raised when using multiple single-line for loops?

Comment: I suggest that you learn some debugging skills. You can start by printing the value of `x` in your loop. For more tips about debugging small programs, read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also, show us which line causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
version = [x["version_value"] for x in version]
references = [x["url"] for x in x["cve"]["references"]["reference_data"]]
```

You're using `x` too often. Use a different name for the loop variables.

```
version = [v["version_value"] for v in version]
references = [r["url"] for r in x["cve"]["references"]["reference_data"]]
```